# Does somebody knows waht the "can't" command does?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: the screenshot I mentioned]So I was experimenting with the terminal in Wsl and happened to enter something that started with "can't" (I don't remember what it was). After that, I entered some sort of note-taking tool or program to execute multiple commands at once.

As you can see, I'm pretty new to Linux and confused as to what "can't" actually does.

I'll add a screenshot in case my explanation confuses you.

Comment: `Can't` doesn't do anything, probably you wrote up a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Bash triggers on `can't` because of single alone quote inside.

So you entered a single quote (`'`), say opening quote, the first.
Bash waits for the second one and shows `>` as temporary prompt to remind you.

Compare the following:

> ```
> $ x='y
> > '
> $
> ```

with

> ```
> $ x='y'
> $
> ```

The same will happen with double quotes.

---

To understand BASH you have to read the docs like https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html .